# Stepper Driver/Motor Voltage with Regulated Power Supply (Arduino)

Tags: power-supply, voltage, stepper-motor

Let me first say I am ***VERY*** new to electronics, so I apologize ahead of time (I'm very active on StackOverflow.com, so I understand).  I have the following components I'm attempting to control with an Arduino Uno:

1. 42BYGHW609 NEMA 17 Stepper
2. DQ420MA Microstep Driver
3. 12V-36V Regulated power supply

All components are listed here:  [at Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/170867711515?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649)

**My question**: Is it safe to connect this regulated power supply directly to my driver and the driver to my motor?  The motor is rated at 1.7A and 3.3V but the driver has 12V in.  Is this a safety hazard?  Do I need to do something to lower the voltage to the motor or does the driver handle this?

Comment: Since it's a set, it looks like the driver provides the motor with the voltage it needs.

Comment: That's what I thought and why I decided on this kit, but before powering everything up I wanted to be sure I wasn't going to fry my equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stepper driver does current limiting. You can set the current limit with the dip switches. Just make sure it is set to OFF-ON-OFF (SW1-SW2-SW3) for 1.7A.

The stepper coils have a resistance of 2 Ohm, so at 1.7A they will require 3.4V. So the math seems to be correct.

PS. the power supply is actually 24V not 12V.

Comment: Awesome, thankyou so much. And yes you're correct it's a 24V, I even tested that earlier with my multimeter. So by setting those DIP switches I could potentially drive a larger stepper?  Like a NEMA 23?

Comment: Yes, you indeed could.